# How can we redirect to particular div in kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I'm using Kohana framework for my project,I've very lengthy login page.Top of the page shows some static description,contains nearly 200 lines of text, while bottom have sign-up and sign-in forms,when an error occurs the fields will be popup with appropriate error messages,but template loads from top,So user unable to see the error messages.To achieve this how can I redirect user to error div when error occurs ? I'm changing template value as follows`if($form_error)
$this->template = 'login#error_div';`
 
but its not working

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect the user to the page with the hash, not set the template's source to be it, which in that context doesn't make sense.

```
if ($form_error) {
    $this->request->redirect("whatever#error_div");
}
```

You may also want to use a better `id` for your errors, maybe `errors`, otherwise you are leaking implementation details to the URL for no benefit.

Comment: When I'm redirecting how you have said,error messages are not displayed because it will treat as new request

Comment: @Mahesh.D If you're following Post/Redirect/Get, then that should not be a problem.